# Any idea why this jquery datepicker control only loads part of the CSS?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

Developing a C#/ASP.Net app and I've used the datepicker control before.  So I imported all the necessary bits from one app to a new one.  In my old app, it looks like this:
[image]

And in my new app, it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the background color is right.  The background gradient image for the word "Next" matches the background image for the Prev and Next arrows, but the layout is completely FUBAR.  Oh, and the Year dropdown overlays the Prev button and the Month dropdown.

Comment: You most likely downloaded the Jquery-UI css.

Comment: I misspoke.  I copied the datepicker piece from my old code and put it into Site.css, which is a CSS file I copied from my old app into the current app's Styles folder.

Comment: Well, that is the colorscheme for your widget etc.  When you utilize the Jquery.Datepicker or calendar, it creates everything with the approperiate classes and ids such that the css files pick it up and manipulate accordingly.  Based on your implementation, it looks like your tds/trs/table doesnt have the correct classes, etc that are utilized in the Calendar/Datepicker object

Comment: So is there a way to correct it?  Do I delete that piece from my CSS file?

Comment: Create both instances, and inspect them both.  See what classes are applied to the elements and attempt to replicate.

Comment: Well, that explains it.  When I upgraded to the latest jquery js files, most of the css classes had changed names.  Got ahold of an updated css file and it's working.  Now I gotta re-tweak my colors.  Thanks!

Comment: np, ill set this as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery-Ui datepicker / calendar tool is formed by 2 components.  the Jquery to build the object and its underlying css file.  Yours does not look the same because the classes and ids assigned are not in the same format as those defined the calendar.  If you wish to occur as such, you need to run both next to each other and inspect them.   You will see a particular set of classes, but ultimately by investigation you will see the differences between the two implementations.

As a sidenote:  you will want to make sure both jqueryui and css are consistent so that way all the files match up with one another.

Overall, when you apply the css correctly, your variant of the calendar will look very similar to that of the original.

Comment: Right on target.  Thanks!  The pitfalls of upgrading to the latest jquery...  ;o)